# Efficient way of joining two query sets without foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I know django doesn't allow joining without a foreign key relation and I can't specify a foreign key because there are entries in one table that are not in the other (populated using pyspark). I need an efficient way to query the following:

Let's say I have the following tables:

Company | Product | Total # Users | Total # Unique Users

and

Company | Product | # Licenses | # Estimated Users

I would like to join such that I can display a table like this on the frontend

Company View

Product|Total # Users|Total # Unique Users|#Licenses|# Estimated Users|

P1     | Num         | Num                | Num     | Num             |

P2     | Num         | Num                | Num     | Num             |

Currently loop through each product and perform a query (way too slow and inefficient) to populate a dictionary of lists

Way too inefficient

Comment: Your reasoning does not follow: if there are "entries in one table that are not in the other" then you can use `null=True` on the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite getting why you can't do a Foreign key in this situation, but if you can implement your query in a sql statement I would look at Q objects. See "Complex Lookups with Q Objects" in the documentation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects